# Чем отличаются  значения союзов?

Tags: союзы, грамматика

Решить задачу с дамами и королями, связанными  различными союзами, не представляет особого труда. Но  вот без  карточного столика определить значение этих союзов сложнее.

Итак, диалог:

- Ты когда собираешься  ехать?
- (1) Наверное,   сегодня вечером или завтра утром.  (2) Наверное, или сегодня вечером, или завтра утром.

Вопрос:  Чем отличаются значения союзов ИЛИ и ИЛИ...ИЛИ  в двух вариантах ответа? Чем они вообще отличаются?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

ДИАЛОГ (На столе карты «Галактиона»)

- Можно взять одну карту. Ты какую возьмешь?
- Думаю, даму или короля./Думаю, или даму, или короля.

Здесь синонимия союзов.

- Можно взять еще карты.
- Я возьму короля и даму.
- Лучше возьми или короля, или даму

Здесь использование союза ИЛИ…ИЛИ  со значением обязательного выбора  соответствует ситуации, когда ПРЕДЛАГАЕТСЯ ОБЪЕДИНЕНИЕ вариантов.

Comment: София, надеюсь сейчас отвечаю на своем поле. Даже и не знал, что есть есть свое и чужое поле. А где диалог, кстати?

Comment: Это моя территория (Вы у меня в гостях), диалог в дополнении, а  отвечать можно здесь.

Comment: Да, София, вы правы! Здесь предлагается объединение вариантов. Поскольку союз "или", как отмечалось выше, имеет частичную омонимию с повторяющимся двойным союзом или...или.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала определимся со значением союза "или".

Союз или

Главное значение основного разделительного союза  или (точная статистика невозможна из-за частичной омонимии с повторяющимся союзом или… или) многократно обсуждалось в отечественной и зарубежной лингвистической литературе [Галкина-Федорук и др. 1958], [Падучева 1964], [Lakoff 1971], [Hurford 1974], [Белошапкова 1977], [Гладкий 1979]. Существуют две основных точки зрения на его семантику.

В классической отечественной русистике и в некоторых западных исследованиях [Wierzbicka 1980] его значение обычно принято трактовать как разделительную дизъюнкцию, или «взаимоисключение» (только одна из сочиненных частей соответствует действительности), т.е. фразы типа – Кто придет? – Маша или Коля интерпретируются как истинные в случае, если придет кто-то один из участников ситуации, но не оба.

В некоторых, главным образом формально ориентированных, исследованиях его значение определяется логически  а именно, как неразделительная дизъюнкция (т.е. действительности может соответствовать или один из конъюнктов, или оба), т.е. фразы типа  Кто придет?  Маша или Коля воспринимаются как приемлемые и в случае прихода обоих участников ситуации.

Языковые примеры дают возможности обеих интерпретаций: Завтра я уже буду в Лондоне или в Париже предполагает, что только одна из возможностей может осуществиться, в то время как фразы типа Если заболит горло или поднимется температура, на прогулку идти нельзя допускают, что обе возможности могут реализоваться одновременно. В данной статье принимается трактовка семантики или, предложенная в работе [Санников 2008], согласно которой выражение X или Y значит, что каждая из этих двух ситуаций возможна, но не обязательна [Санников 2008: 193]:

(136) Во время приготовления два или три раза встряхивать посуду. [Рецепты национальных кухонь: Франция (2000-2005)]

Фразы типа Здесь близко река или озеро согласно [Санников 2008: 193] означают, что «возможно, река есть, а может ее и нет; то же самое следует сказать об озере». Естественные интерпретации этой фразы подразумевают, что либо река, либо озеро есть, а если бы их не было, то Говорящий представил бы третью опцию (Здесь близко река или озеро, а если нет, то должен быть хотя бы ручей). Таким образом, сама по себе семантика или не предписывает непременного соответствия действительности по крайней мере одного из конъюнктов, но в отсутствие третьей опции такое соответствие выводится из прагматических закономерностей, в частности постулата информативности П. Грайса [Grice 1975].

У или есть ряд не-разделительных употреблений, которые в данной статье не рассматриваются (или противительный (Перестань болтать, или из класса выгоню), или пояснительный (трансгенные, или генно-модифицированные организмы), или присоединительный (Они рассаживались на диванах, на стульях, на кроватях или просто на полу) и пр.).

***Союзы или... или***

Двойной союз ***или... или и*** его более редкий синоним либо... либо отличаются от одиночных союзов чистой разделительности ***или и либо тем,*** что указывают на обязательность хотя бы одного из компонентов (отмечается в [Санников 2008]); ср. Мне поможет Таня или Маша, а если у них не будет времени  то Наташа, при странности ?Мне поможет или Таня или Маша, а если у них не будет времени  то Наташа. Ср. также:

(140) Или мы тебя сажаем, или ты уходишь в лес [Г. Хирачев (А. Ганиева). Салам тебе, Далгат! (2009)]

(141) Остальные пять лет вы внимаете рассуждениям однокурсников о смысле жизни и незаметно становитесь либо нравоучительным педантом, либо циником-эгоистом [Н. Щербак. Роман с филфаком (2010)] Источник: ***Русская корпусная грамматика.***

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за развернутый ответ.  Итак, повторение союза свидетельствует об обязательности выбора, а одиночный союз такую обязательность не гарантирует. Получается, что при синонимии повторяющийся союзов  союз ИЛИ…ИЛИ просто усиливает категоричность высказывания, поэтому мы часто применяем их, особенно не задумываясь над значением.

Comment: В то же время приведенные примеры необязательного выбора для союза ИЛИ – это не совсем чистый эксперимент. В предложениях «Если заболит горло или поднимется температура, на прогулку идти нельзя»  и «Здесь близко река или озеро» мы видим открытый ряд однородных членов, который можно продолжить: если заболит горло, если поднимется температура, если будет кашель и др., река, или озеро, или пруд, или др. В дополнении к вопросу я приведу еще один диалог, в котором, как мне кажется,  союзы неравнозначны.

Answer (score 0):

Тем, что в одном случае они являются повторяющимися при однородных членах предложения. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне как раз хочется узнать, ПОЧЕМУ союз ИЛИ повторяется.

Comment: София, вы имеете в виду повторяющийся союз или или? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Серж, Вы почему-то отвечаете в комментариях не на своем поле, Вас никак не найдешь. Это ответ для Tagirix, а Вы посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к моему ответу и добавьте комментарий в мой или свой ответ.